# Where to locate E2E tests relies on more than one repository

Tags: testing, repository, e2e-testing, playwright

This topic does not seem to have any best-practice documentation.

I maintain two main repositories:
The MainRepository1, the MainRepository2.

Four E2E tests were created to be executed every time each main repository completes deployment steps.

**What is the best place to locate the tests?** 
The code should not be duplicated.

Are there any best practices here?

Avoid duplications of tests

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about any best practice, but myself would put the E2E tests in a third repository to check out and run in each of the 2 main repository pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

> Use [environment Variables](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#passing-environment-variables) to keep automation code app environment
> agnostic like dev- qa- stage - prod.

This way you run the same tests in multiple environments by passing changes as environment variables or through command line arguments.

This applies to any automation not only to playwright.